# Facebook Ads API Error - The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, interface

I'm using the Graph Api Explorer reaying to get available leads setting the AD ID and I'm getting the following error...

/AD_ID/leads

(OAuthException - #274) (#274) The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API. Please add it in developer.facebook.com -> application -> settings -> advanced -> advertising accounts -> Ads API. Account XXXX not enabled for application 145634995501895.

If I try to fo the same using the SDK I got the same error.

But if I do the same query using the Form_ID, it works OK.

/FORM_ID/leads

I already set up the AD account "Please add it in developer.facebook.com -> application -> settings -> advanced -> advertising accounts -> Ads API", but I'm still getting the same error.

What is killing me is why the query works with the form_id and with the ad_id don´t.

Please help me :)

Thanks in advance,

Martin.-

Comment: Well did you do what the message asks you to …?

Comment: I'd take a guess that this is because you have permission to retrieve the leads from the form but not per-ad - and they encounter the error and return the default 2xx error.

Same thing happens if I try it incidentally.

Comment: You really need to do what the message is asking you to do.

Answer (score 2):

> You can not use Graph API Explorer App for Marketing API.
>
> You need to make your own app and then add the ad account in that app.

Comment: Strangely, but this is true.